# Inline SVG not scaling as viewport changes...?

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to get an SVG I wrote / drew to scale as the viewport changes, it's the reason I chose sVG as the format for the image.

However, it doesn't seem to be scaling at all.

I did all that my research told me to, added width, height and some attributes to the SVG element and added a div container-parent; and, then added max-height / width and height / width : 100% in CSS to that.

Any idea why this SVG is not scaling and how I can get it to scale?

Here is a live example of the page in question : https://dl.dropbox.com/u/270523/inlineSVG.html

Comment: Why this `#bookmark {max-width: 106px;}` ?

Comment: @Duopixel:
I don't want the inline svg, child of #bookmark, to have a width greater than 106px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS on `#bookmark` state: `width: 100%; max-width: 106px;` this means that the svg will never scale unless the window is less that 106px wide (which most/all browsers do not allow).

It is difficult to discern exactly what you want to achieve, but if you state `width: 10%` you will observe the SVG is indeed scaling according to the browser width.

Comment: It kind of works, but it still overflows / is sometimes too big. Is there nothing I can do about that?

Besides style the width and height in each of my breakpoints in their corresponding media-queries ?

Comment: @IMUXIxD if you want to prevent the SVG from becoming too big then reduce `max-width`. Make an effort to understand what's going on so you can adjust it to your liking.